# Limit number of posts in wp loop

Tags: custom-taxonomy, limit

I am using this code to get posts of specific taxonomy. It displays 10 posts by default. How can I set my own limit?

```
<?php 
    $count = 1; 
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'brand' => 'sony-vaio' ) );
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To display 5 posts, say, use `posts_per_page`. See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'brand' => 'sony-vaio','posts_per_page'=>5 ) );
```